# sending a png image over a websocket and rendering the received image

Tags: image, websocket, png, arraybuffer

On server:
I am loading a png image:

```
var myimage = png.load('test.png');

then sending over websocket connection:
ws.send(myimage);
```

On client:

```
function onMessage(evt) {
    if (evt.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        var length = evt.data.byteLength;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(evt.data);
        var image = document.getElementById("image");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ window.btoa(bytes);
        var ctx = image.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Not getting anything to display on canvas. Any ideas about what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a blob and converting that to a blob url

```
function onMessage(evt) {
    if (evt.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        var length = evt.data.byteLength;
        var blob = new Blob([evt.data],{type:'image/png'});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var image = document.getElementById("image");
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
        img.src = url;
}
```